# Youtube iframe javascript, track percentage of video watched?

Tags: javascript, youtube

I am trying to get an accurate calculation of how much time a user has spent watching a video. The time they spent watching it should not include skipping forward or when the video is paused. The code I have now is giving me a different percentage each time (I'm using an interval). I don't know how else to go about this?

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      clicked_video = true; 
      arr.length = (player.getDuration()-1).toFixed(0);
      done = true;

    }if(event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING){

       id = setInterval(check, 1000);

   }if(event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED || event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING){

        clearInterval(id);
        var percent = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
          if(arr[i] == "x"){
          percent++;
          console.log(percent);
          }

       }

    percent = (percent / arr.length) * 100;
    alert(percent + "%");
    }
}
function check(){

      arr[Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime())] = "x";
}
```

Comment: You're talking about a percentage of the video that has been watched, and about how much time the user spent watching. Those are 2 different things. What if a user plays the video until 1:00 and then comes back to 0:30 until the end? Do you count that as an extra, or do you only want that to count for a minute?

Comment: yeah i only want to count that for a minute. So overall time the user watched the video, then calculate it as a percentage afterwards i guess

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a demo, I think the variables and functions have names explicit enough to understand everything, but if you have any question or problem, go ahead and ask.

One thing I have to mention is that **it won't be exact**. If your interval gets executed once per second and the user skips a part in the middle of a second, that one might not be counted. To have a more accurate percentage, you can execute your interval more often (100ms here, I got 97% when watching the video back and forth), but be careful not to use too much resources.

```
var player, timer, timeSpent = [], display = document.getElementById('display');

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player( 'player', {
        events: { 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange }
    });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(event.data === 1) { // Started playing
        if(!timeSpent.length){
            timeSpent = new Array( parseInt(player.getDuration()) );
        }
        timer = setInterval(record,100);
    } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}

function record(){
    timeSpent[ parseInt(player.getCurrentTime()) ] = true;
    showPercentage();
}

function showPercentage(){
    var percent = 0;
    for(var i=0, l=timeSpent.length; i<l; i++){
        if(timeSpent[i]) percent++;
    }
    percent = Math.round(percent / timeSpent.length * 100);
    display.innerHTML = percent + "%";
}
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: Thank you! Was very helpful. I still don't quite get what I was doing wrong however, would it be possible for you to explain my issue?

Comment: @dantheman Yes, sorry about that. Well, as you had some variables that were not declared in the code you posted, and some things that did not seem useful at first sight, I didn't look at it that much. One thing I'm sure of is that you can't set `arr.length` directly, you need to push values to it until you get the desired length. **Edit** Instead of pushing all the values, you can set the array length by doing `timeSpent = new Array( parseInt(player.getDuration()) );`.

Comment: Ahhh i see thank you so much for all your help, i would give your answer an upvote but apparently i dont have enough 'reputation' for that XD

Comment: If I change the seek(progress) bar, it doesn't change which is bad :)

Comment: @SaiTejaReddy That's the desired behavior. When you go back to a part of the video that has already been watched, the percentage won't change (we don't want to count it twice). And if we go to a part that hasn't been watched yet, it does increase the percentage.

Comment: Have anyone tried this on iOS? Does this still work?

Comment: My video player functions were actually under event.target using it in React with the react-youtube package.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a way to get a frame-perfect precision of how much of the video the user has watched:

### The recipe

- Get a reference to the HTML5 video player
- Grab the `played` property off the video object, which returns a `TimeRanges` object (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TimeRanges)
- Iterate over the `played` object, and add up all the ranges

### Example

```
/**
 *
 * @param {HTMLVideoElement} video
 * @returns {{total: number, percent: number}}
 */
function getPlayedTime(video) {
    var totalPlayed = 0;
    var played = video.played;

    for (var i = 0; i < played.length; i++) {
        totalPlayed += played.end(i) - played.start(i);
    }

    return {
        total: totalPlayed,
        percent: totalPlayed / video.duration * 100
    };
}
```

By calling the above helper function and passing it your video object, you'll get back an object with two properties: the total length (in seconds) that the user actually watched, and the percentage of the video's duration that this represents.

The cool thing about this approach is that it is 100% accurate. If the user watches the first 5 seconds of the video over and over, it'll still register that only 5 seconds were watched. The browser itself keeps track of this, so you don't need to set intervals, listen for events, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to adapt this code for use with YouTube embeds? I don't see how / where to get the `video` object that I'd pass as an argument to your function.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if I replay the video in a previously played segment, for example if I restart the video in the segment [0..8] in second 4, played will not create a new segment, and it will continue counting in that same segement.

For example, if I restart in 4, and continue playing until 13, the segment [0..8] will become [0..13].

This makes sense given that the played property tells us which time ranges have been played within the media.

Answer (score 1):

Youtube iframe player api provide a function to turn the current played time of the video `player.getCurrentTime():Number`. That can be used to track how much the user watched the video.

You can also make use of `player.getDuration()` api to get the total video time and calculate the percentage of the progress

here is the alternation of the exampled shared by first answer http://jsfiddle.net/ndbseftp/